# How can i open an apk app with android studion and modify it

Tags: android, visual-studio, apk

I have an androidp app ans i need to modify it, how can i have the source code from apk file and open it with android studio for modification.

thank's a lot

Comment: Even if you manage to modify it, the digital signature will be no longer valid. Unless you have a copy of the original vendor's private key, you'll have to sign it with your own key for distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reality you can't decompile arbitrary Android apps back to a Gradle / Android Studio project, modify it, recompile it and get back an APK that works like the original one (except for your modifications).

First there are different types of Android apps, as there are now quite a few development frameworks and a lot of them don't rely on Android Studio and Java/Kotlin code or only for certain parts of the apps. Frameworks like React-Natice, Flutter, Xamarin, .Net Maui...
For each framework you need a different decompiler (if a decompiler and recompiler exists at all)

For regular Java/Kotkin based Android apps you can use [apktool](https://apktool.org/) which decompiles an app to smali code. Sami is very low level so development is a pain, but it has the advantage that the chance to be able to rebuild an app after modification is high.

Alternatively there is Jadx which can decompile an Java/Kotlin based app to Java code, but that code often has problems or has light differences to the original code. [Jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx) als has an option to build an Gradle project the would allow Android Studio to open the decompiled app as project. But effectively using this for decompiling, modifying and recompiling an app will only work for very small apps.

Comment: thank you a lot for your explications, it's very helpful